# How to solve acceleration due to gravity without time?

Tags: linear-algebra

If you have a dot on a computer screen that you launch from 90 pixels high with a velocity of 100 at an angle of 0, and it lands on the bottom of the screen 150 pixels away, what is its acceleration due to gravity?

Recording time from launch with a stopwatch is inaccurate, so I'd rather solve this without time as it's not necessary (I know it isn't because I've solved it before but have forgotten)

Once again there should be no time variable, to solve this using time is all over the internet, I need the equation without time, as can be done when you know initial velocity (100), initial height (90 pixels), horizontal distance (150 pixels), and vertical distance that it fell (90 pixels) from the known launch angle (0)

Comment: You shouldn't say "acceleration due to gravity", since that would be a particular value, but rather just "acceleration".

Answer (score 4):

We do not need to be given the travel time, since the information supplied is enough to determine that.

If the time to fall is $t$, then the horizontal distance travelled is $100t$. But this is $150$, so $t=1.5$.

If the acceleration is $a$, then the distance fallen in time $t$ is $\frac{1}{2}at^2$. This is $90$.

Thus $\frac{1}{2}a(1.5)^2=90$. That gives $a=\dfrac{(2)(90)}{(1.5)^2}$.

**Remark:** A similar calculation can be made for any known launch angle $\theta$. We have tacitly assumed that acceleration is constant. In particular, the calculation neglects the (possibly very considerable) effect of air resistance.

**Mentioning time less:** Let $v_{\text{av}}$ be the average downward velocity. Then $\frac{v_{\text{av}}}{90}=\frac{100}{150}$. But $v_{\text{av}}=\frac{1}{2}a\frac{150}{100}$. It follows that $a=(2)(90)\left(\frac{100}{150}\right)^2$.

Comment: Since the time you gave, 1.5, is an arbitrary measure of time, there is no need to include it, it only complexes the answer, it isn't the "minimal", or simplest answer. It can be done without the time variable.

Comment: Indeed it can. My feeling is that an argument that mentions only distance, velocity, and acceleration (and thus $t$ implicitly rather than explicitly) is more difficult to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

Acceleration is defined as the second derivative of position with respect to time, or the first derivative of velocity with respect to time. Time is an intrinsic property of the measurement. You cannot do it without time.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms *ahem* I don't know what you're talking about... ;)

Comment: when the velocity of editing becomes relativistic we possibly arrive at non-causality...

Comment: I have done it without time before. This is a computer program we are talking about, not real baseball. Time can be randomized, or instantaneous in the computer world. In order to plot a line of the trajectory, you define an arbitrary "timestep" for each point to draw the line between to make the curve, but to determine the start and endpoint, you only need to know initial velocity, initial position, and launch angle to determine landing position (on any ground x,y coordinate you choose). If you can't answer the question it's fine.

Comment: @LukeAllen Picking some time step--whether it be 1 hour, 1 second, or 1 year--is very much not the same as "not using time". In which case, Andre Nicolas' answer is exactly what you need.